# running multiple commands using sequelize cli

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have the following migration file but i get this error:

`TypeError: queryInterface.addConstraint is not a function`

Can anyone enlighten me on how this should be written?

```
'use strict';
const uuidV4 = require('uuid/v4');

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('app_users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: function () {
          return uuidV4()
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      disabled: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: false
      }
    }).then(function () {
      return queryInterface.addConstraint('app_users', ['email'], {
        type: 'unique',
        name: 'unique_email'
      });
    })
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('app_users');
  }
};
```

Sequelize [Node: 7.10.0, CLI: 2.7.0, ORM: 4.0.0-2]

Comment: what does `console.log(queryInterface)` output inside the problematic `then()` ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to do with the way you chain your queries. I ran into the same issue and asked on the sequelize slack group and it turns out that `addConstraint` is going to be released in v4. Although I think we may have both seen it in the docs and thought it was available.